# Centering figure on Landscape A3 page

Tags: graphics, floats, landscape

I've been attempting to insert a figure on a landscape A3 page in an A4 document, but I proves hard. Ideally, the figure would fill the whole page (It's an A3 figure), but it's more important with continuous page numbering so I can settle for a centered image. :-)

I have the following code at the moment, this produce the result seen in the image.

```
\chapter{Poster}\label{app:poster}

Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

\afterpage{
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,pagesize} 
\recalctypearea
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent

\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=2.6\textwidth]{gfx/poster}}%

\vspace*{2cm}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}
\pagebreak
```

[image: Figure of what's produced by attached code.]

Comment: I don't get how you can insert an A3 page in an A4 page.

Comment: There is no A3 page inserted in an A4 page. There is an A3 page in an A4 document. Where on that A3 page I would like for the figure to be either centered, or filling the whole page. See figure.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to make your figure on an A4 page? I don't know if it''s possible to have an A3 page in an A4 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\noindent

\makebox[\textwidth]
```

does not stop the box being indented, it makes a blank paragraph just consisting of `\parfillskip` glue, then the vertical `\parskip` glue, and then the box starts an indented paragraph, so visually it moves the image down by a line and to the right by the paragraph indentation.

The rest of the space is due to page margins, usually such layouts require some hand tuning of the image position to look good so I would just use

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-10,20){\includegraphics{...}}
\end{picture}
```

then the image is in a zero sized box so latex won't complain, and by adjusting the coordinates in `\put` you can make it go anywhere on the page, or be larger than the page and bleed off the edges, or whatever you need.